# Probability to draw a group of balls which contains a specific ball

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A bin holds n balls, labeled with the numbers $1, 2, . . . , n$. Exactly $m$ balls are being
>   sampled uniformly at random from the bin. Let $M$ be the maximum number that was drawn.
>
> 1. Compute the distribution of $M$, when the samples are being made without replacement.

My answer:

We need to calculate $P(M=k)$

I have 2 answers which result in 2 different values.

1. We must draw the $k$'th ball ($1$ way to do it) and then we need to choose the rest of the balls ($\binom{k-1}{m-1}$). There are $\binom{n}{m}$ ways to choose $m$ balls from $n$ balls:

$$\frac{1\cdot\binom{k-1}{m-1}}{\binom{n}{m}}$$

2. We must draw the $k$'th ball $\frac{1}{n}$  and then we need to choose the rest of the balls $\binom{k-1}{m-1}$. The probability to choose each of these balls is:

$$ \frac{1}{n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{n-2}\cdots\frac{1}{n-m} $$

So the final result is:

$$ \frac{1}{n}\cdot\binom{k-1}{m-1}\cdot\frac{1}{n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{n-2}\cdots\frac{1}{n-m} = $$

$$ \frac{1}{n}\cdot\binom{k-1}{m-1}\cdot\frac{(n-m-1)!}{n!} $$

---

**My question** - Each result is different. Which is the correct one and why is the other not correct?

Answer (score 2):

The first method is the correct one, but method number 2 can be fixed. I will try to point out the errors and fix them:

> - The product $$\frac1{n-1}\cdot\frac1{n-2}\cdots\frac1{n-m}$$ should have stopped at $n-m+1$ instead, since otherwise you would draw $m+1$ balls as a total.
> - The fraction $1/n$ should be included as part of $n!$ in the denominator in the last line, since the other fractions only have $n-1,n-2$ etc.
> - Finally you should multiply the whole thing by the $m!$ different orders in which those $m$ balls could be drawn.

After doing this, the two actually agree since they both become:
$$
\binom{k-1}{m-1}\cdot\frac{(n-m)!\cdot m!}{n!}
$$
if you look carefully.

---

Note that method 1 considers combinations where order does not matter, whereas method 2 thinks through probabilities for each specific sequence of events and hence permutations where order does matter. That is what prompted the correction of a factor $m!$ in the method 2 approach. In method 1 that factor $m!$ is just already an element of the formula for the orderless $\binom{n}{m}$.

Comment: I didn't understand why you multiply by $m!$. `whereas method 2 thinks through probabilities for each specific sequence of events ` -  I didn't multiply by $m!$. The order of the balls doesn't matter.

Comment: @StavAlfi: Let me clarify by providing an example: Let us say that we have drawn the sequence $1,4,2$ from $1,2,3,4,5$. Thus we have $n=5,m=3,k=4$. The probability of this happening is $$\frac1n\cdot\frac1{n-1}\frac1{n-2}$$ using the exact reasoning you gave. But surely drawing $2,1,4$ has the same probability. So we have to count that probability as well. The same for each of the $3!$ permutations of $1,2,4$. Hence we must multiply by $3!$.

Comment: @StavAlfi: The binomial coefficient $\binom{4-1}{3-1}$ only counts the set of numbers $1,2,4$ once (or more specifically the subset $1,2$ once), but the probabilities must be compounded for each specific sequence order, since the probability formula you gave points to individual permutations where order matters.

Comment: Thanks. You are pointing out that I must count all permutations in my second approach while you wrote that my first approach is correct even thought I didn't care about the order (permutations) there: `The first method is the correct one` , `Note that method 1 considers combinations where order does not matter`. I'm sure I'm missing something in your explanation.

Comment: @StavAlfi: The thing is that the probability figure:$$\frac1n\cdot\frac1{n-1}\cdots\frac1{n-m+1}$$computes the probability of drawing a specific sequence of $m$ balls in a specific order. Thus order matters. The orderless equivalent is:$$\frac1n\cdot\frac1{n-1}\cdots\frac1{n-m+1}\cdot m!$$

Answer (score 2):

I would say $$P(M = k)=P(M \le k)-P(M \le k-1) =\dfrac{k \choose m}{n \choose m}-\dfrac{k-1 \choose m}{n \choose m} = \dfrac{m{k \choose m}}{k{n \choose m}}=\dfrac{{k-1 \choose m-1}}{{n \choose m}}$$ so the first option in the question

The second option is too small and does not add up to $1$

Comment: `and does not add up to 1` - What does it mean?

Comment: @StavAlfi if you take a particular values for $n$ and $m$ and add up the $P(M=k)$ for $k=m$ to $n$ you will not get the $1$ that you should since $M$ takes exactly one of those values with probability $1$.   For example with $n=10, m=4$ you get $0.000694444\ldots = \frac{1}{1440}$

Comment: It's a nice way to test my answer. Thank you.